# Class not registered Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154

Tags: c#, winforms, interop

when I run the application it always returns the following error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {998B125A-4959-4A18-A805-CC5500DF0A71} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I am working with a WinForms application with framework 3.5, and I compile in x86, since my OS is Win 7 32 bit

I have registered the libraries as follows:

```
regasm c:\code\Interop.SecurityProvider.dll
```

Comment: Can you explain the history of your project.  Is this first time using project?  Did you copy project from another project?  Did you update Visual Studio?

Comment: The original project was made in VB6, another developer passed it to .net 3.5. but when using the libraries I gave the same errors that I listed above. I built a virtual with Win 7 32 bits with VS2019.
I looked at the registry and found the GUID of the library

Comment: You should not be using a VB6 library.  There should be an equivalent Net 3.5 library.  It looks like you are using the Net Library System.Runtime.InteropServices.  I would open Solution Explorer in VS and look at the path for the library.  Make sure path is the version in framework 3.5.  What methods is the Interop.SecurityProvider.dll using?  It looks like you have two different versions of Interop that are conflicting.

Comment: the runtime version of the library is 2.0.50727, the methods used are AuthenticationMethods, DataBaseEnvironments, User, and Info

Comment: If you go to control panel and check installed software is Net 2.0 Installed?  Which version of Net are installed?  If I remember correctly Net 3.5 only ran on 32 Win 7.  Then in Net 4.0 there were two version one ran on 32 bit and one on 64.  I also thought that Net 3.5 required Net 1.0, 2.0, 2.5, and 3.0 installed.  You didn't specify which version of VS you were using.  I guess you must have Net 4.7 installed and Building with Net 3.5 option since you have VS2019.  x86 doesn't make a difference but you should not be using 64 bit.